# What is the shell of a USB-C plug for?

Tags: pinout, usb-c

A USB-C has this characteristic shell (the outermost visible metal part). Would the connection still work without any problems if i were to remove the shell (given that all the pins still line up)?
For example in the new MacBook Pros the shell of the USB-C ports melt seamlessly into the chassis which is what i'd want to achieve.

Comment: Most likely it will still work, but maybe not compliant anymore, e.g. signal integrity, emi, mechanical strength.

Comment: What for? With old usb and the tiny sticks I can somewhat understand this, but with C the metal part saves you almost nothing in space.

Comment: You cannot have good signal integrity at MAX speed without proper shell, shielding, cable and RF Cap grounding for extended BW with 15dB return loss.!

Answer (score 2):

**Will USB-C plug work without chassis of the connector?**
Yes, it will most likely work with short distances, on your desk, as long as at least one side still has chassis connected.

**Will it still comply to USB?**
No, USB **requires** a chassis connector for numerous reasons.

- For signal integrity, the chassis of the connector shields all signals of the cable from the outside world inside the cable. The cable has shielded foil around all conductors. Breaking this shield is not recommended.
  USB 3 is very high speed with relative weak signals.
- For physical integrity, the chassis provides all the latching features and strength the connector has. It also prevents misalignment of the connector.

If you want your socket to be flush you will have to use a metal enclosure with your custom socket. Or use any of the existing options that will extend trough the enclosure.
[image: USB C sockets]

Shield is at approximately the same potential as GND, but it is not used as return path for power.

[USB C pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktaUI.jpg)